# mod_rewrite, execute rules if substring found

Tags: mod-rewrite

Here is an example of old url:

`index.php/component/option,com_fireboard/Itemid,180/catid,15/func,view/id,4272/#4339`

And now url is like

`index.php/component/option,com_kunena/Itemid,180/catid,15/func,view/id,4272/#4339`

So, can you help me how to redirect via mod_rewrite if com_fireboard found in query string, and just replace it with "com_kunena"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
RewriteRule (.*)com_fireboard(.*) $1com_kunena$2
```